# Visual Basic error: expression does not produce a value

Tags: vb.net

How can I fix this error?
I have imported `System.IO.File`

error: expression does not produce a value

```
Imports System.IO.File
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox9.Clear()
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        TextBox3.Text = "something"
    End If
    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        TextBox3.Text = textbox3.text + "other things.."
    End If
    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        TextBox3.Text = replace(textbox3.text, "a", "b")
    End If

 write = System.IO.File.AppendText("myfilepath")
        write.WriteLine(TextBox3.Text)
        write.Close()
End Sub
```

This line gets an error:

```
TextBox3.Text = replace(textbox3.text, "a", "b")
```

error:

```
Expression does not produce a value.
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8eXy.png)

Comment: This is vb.net Code, so please Remove your vba-tag

Comment: Are you sure, you are getting the said error in above posted code?

Comment: There is nothing there that needs `System.IO.File`. that code wont produce that error

Comment: Did you Post your complete Code? If not, please also Post your stacktrace.

Comment: @etalon11 `expression does not produce a value` is a compiler error, there will be no stack trace

Comment: Since the capitalization is all messed up, it is possible you have a local method named `replace` which is shadowing out the legacy VB function (or that is just not the real code still)

Comment: If you have a Compiler error, please make a Screenshot and Show it to us.

Comment: you have a void method (Sub) named `replace` somewhere which does not produce an expression.  the compiler is using that instead of the MS VB function you want it to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change the line of code like this:

```
TextBox3.Text = Strings.Replace(textbox3.text, "a", "b")
```

Or like this:

```
TextBox3.Text = TextBox3.Text.Replace("a", "b")
```

In Visual Studio when you go hover with mouse, you can get some information, as the Namespace of the function/class etc... check it too.

**Updated with explanation**

The import of `System.IO.File`brings with it a method that does not produce results, so forcing the full name of the namespace (`Strings.replace(...)`), the issue is resolved, and there is no more conflict between the methods with the same name.

[*The MS guide for the method in namespace `System.IO.File`*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.replace(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The problem was caused by the `Imports System.IO.File` which results in `Replace` being assumed to be `File.Replace` which is a void method (a Sub) that does not return a value.

Comment: @Blackwood yet another reason to prefer the NET versions over the legacy VB functions!   ...(and paste actual code - the small 'r' resulted in a red herring compared to the image).